# Is there a way to quickly select multiple items from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a list of subsets of `n` of length 3.  However, my approaches are quite slow, and it takes a while to run the whole program.

My "code" so far is just the generic iterative approach.

```
subs = []
for a in vertices:
    for b in vertices:
        for c in vertices:
            if sorted([a, b, c]) not in subs and a != b and b != c:
                subs.append(sorted([a, b, c]))
```

This is quite slow, but I'm not sure exactly how I could speed it up.  Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import itertools
xs = [1, 2, 3,4]
print(list(itertools.combinations(xs, 3)))
```

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I definitely wouldn't have found that in the python docs

Comment: Great! If it works, please help me and upvote and accept the solution :)

Comment: I'm upvoting, but since I'm new, it doesn't show it publicly.  I will accept it in 8 minutes.  (Apparently Stack Overflow requires a 15-minute wait)

Comment: This doesn't give quite the same results as the question's code, as it never repeats the same value more than once in a tuple (e.g. `(1, 1, 1)`, which is in the question's output but not this code's). If that repetition is desired, you want `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` instead of `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  I'm gonna edit my post, since I don't want repeats.  I didn't even notice that myself!